# e-mail templates - horizontal padding of floating spans cut off at linebreak

Tags: html, css, email, css-float, email-templates

I'm strunggling at building E-Mail templates. Displaying some words inline using spans (trying to avoid the display property because some outlook versions don't support it) a floating problem occurs.

Problem case: the whole span including padding doesn't fit into the current line, so the text breaks into the next line - fine for now. The "left" padding though unfortunately stays in the first line and gets "cut off" the item as you can see in this screenshot.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf3qK.png)

```
<span style=" line-height:25px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size:11px; background:#EBEBEB; border-radius: 8px;a padding: 3px 10px; margin:0;">
    Vollzeit
</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
```

How can I force the padding to stick with the text and make it jump into the next line, too?
(This problem doesn't occur in outlook only but also on several other e-mail clients.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using tables instead since email clients have notoriously nasty support for a wide gamut of other markup and styles. Chris Coyier has a good article on responsive emails here https://css-tricks.com/ideas-behind-responsive-emails/ Look at the section specifically around 3 columns where he states:

> You might think: each of those will be a `<td>`. But no, if that was the case you'd never be able to get them to wrap in the limited CSS world of emails.

It's yucky looking but, some variation of the following might work http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoyojN

```html
<table class="main-wrapping-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align="left" style="width: 33.33%">
            </table>
            <table align="left" style="width: 33.33%">
            </table>
            <table align="left" style="width: 33.33%">
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```